# Debug steps for celery chord not running in Django with RabbitMQ broker and DB backend?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, chord

I am struggling to debug an issue I have all of a sudden been hitting and would value some advice.

I am using celery 3.1.18 with Django, with RabbitMQ as the broker and an Oracle database as the backend, ie.:

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'

My code makes use of chords and has been working successfully for a year or so now.

All of a sudden chords are not firing the callback across both my Dev and Prod envs and I am at a loss as to how to debug further. The code has not changed and last night, without changing the code *something I did made chords come back to life temporarily only to stop working again this morning .. suggesting this is some sort of resource issue rather than a code problem.

So far, I have:

1. restarted the host that rabbitmq-server and celery are running on.
2. purged all queues and repeated step 1.
3. Disabled the backend (commented it out from settings.py, got the error about disabled backend, then enabled the backend once again.
4. Tried to run the basic commands that show chords working in the docs. The example hangs on the shell and when you CTRL-C out you get:

   from celery import chord
   from tasks import add, sum
   callback = tsum.s()
   header = [add.s(i, i) for i in range(100)] result = chord(header)(callback)
   result.get()

   ^CTraceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get no_ack=no_ack, File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 220, in wait_for on_interval() File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 181, in maybe_reraise_parent_error node.maybe_reraise() File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 485, in maybe_reraise result.maybe_reraise() File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 270, in maybe_reraise if self.state in states.PROPAGATE_STATES: File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 394, in state return self.get_task_meta()['status'] File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 339, in _get_task_meta return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id)) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 292, in get_task_meta meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/backends/database.py", line 40, in _get_task_meta_for return self.TaskModel._default_manager.get_task(task_id).to_dict() File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 144, in get_task return self.get(task_id=task_id) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(args, *kwargs) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get num = len(clone) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len self._fetch_all() File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all self._result_cache = list(self.iterator()) File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 211, in iterator if connections[self.db].features.supports_select_related: File "/opt/exaboard/eXaboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 900, in db @property KeyboardInterrupt

Any advice on how to DEBUG further would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you by any chance upgrade to Django 1.9?  I did so recently on some celery-based projects, only to find celery was no longer working.  It was amidst a bunch of upgrades, but after smacking my head against a wall I realized that celery hadn't rolled out Django 1.9 support.  After I downgraded to Django 1.8, things ran much more smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am actually running Django 1.7.7 have been running successfully on that version for quite some time.